# MobileFirst authenticationConfig.xml 7.1 migration error on Security Access Manager sample project - how to resolve?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, isam, mobilefirst-cli

I'm working with IBM MobileFirst 7.1, and trying to get integration for ISAM working. So far I've been working with the sample application provided [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24034222), but I'm having issues with it when working with 7.1 MobileFirst client-side tools.

If I download and unzip the v3.5 integration package, and unzip the ISAMforMobileFirst test project, and I build it with the v7.0 CLI, it builds successfully. However, if I build it with the v7.1 CLI, I get an error like this:

```
Migrating project from version 7.0.0.00.20150211-0917 to version 7.1.0.00.20150807-0630.
[Error:
BUILD FAILED
/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI-7.1/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml:497: com.worklight.upgrader.UpgradeEngineException: FWLPL0019E: Migrating the ISAMforMobileFirst project from version 7.0.0.00.20150211-0917 to version 7.1.0.00.20150807-0630 has failed because Cannot parse /Users/ferriera/Downloads/AmWorklightAdapter-3.5/sample/ISAMforMobileFirst/server/conf/authenticationConfig.xml
    at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.upgradeProject(WLUpgradeEngine.java:271)
    at com.worklight.upgrader.ant.UpgraderTask.execute(UpgraderTask.java:100)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

A colleague also sees this exact error in MobileFirst Studio 7.1 (in Eclipse) so I'm guessing it's not a CLI-specific error.

I would assume that support for something has changed in `authenticationConfig.xml` in 7.1, and this hasn't been reflected in the migrator.

A few questions:

1. Is ISAM integration supported in 7.1?
2. Whilst I realise the sample application isn't technically supported in 7.1, if/since ISAM integration is, in theory it should be feasible to make it work. What's changed in authenticationConfig.xml syntax?

Comment: Did you compare the authenticationConfig.xml of old with new?

Comment: It's the *same* `authenticationConfig.xml` - exactly the same project. The problem I think is that the migrator for 7.1 can't parse the 7.0 `authenticationConfig.xml` format.

Comment: In case it helps, I've uploaded the `authenticationConfig.xml` exactly as it comes from the package when we download it here: https://gist.github.com/andrewferrier/4aa16a18639628f054a8

Comment: Failing as well here, bug. Open a PMR.

Comment: I will as soon as I can. But I was wondering if there was any way to guess/theorise as to what was wrong inside the `authenticationConfig.xml` so I could manually fix it. On the assumption the LTPA/HTTP Header support hasn't been completed removed, I think it should still be possible to make it work.

Comment: There are no developer resources to debug it w/out a PMR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: looks like the failure happens due to the following: `<parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-file-path" value="<file-path>"/>` and more specifically: `<file-path>`.

Change it to the actual file path, and it will not fail importing.

---

Nothing in the authenticationConfig.xml file is about ISAM really; it's all declarations of realms, login modules, security tests...

There is a clear failure, and a PMR should be opened.
As for a local workaround, I've attempted to remove segments in the file that I thought might trigger it, but did not succeed to find a pattern that causes it...

Comment: Yeah, I've opened a PMR. I'll trace it through that.

Comment: Bingo, that looks like it, thanks. I'm guessing this means the migrator is more picky than the regular MFP 7.0 build command. Irrespective, changing `<file-path>` to a real file path, even a non-existent one, causes `mfp build` to succeed. Thanks!

Comment: where is the exact file path btw?